# PHPMailer Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Tags: centos, phpmailer

```html
2017-05-11 04:12:04 Connection: opening to ssl://webnode.aquatis.host:465, timeout=3, options=array ( ) 2017-05-11 04:12:05 Connection: opened 
2017-05-11 04:12:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2017-05-11 04:12:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO manager.aquatis.host 
2017-05-11 04:12:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2017-05-11 04:12:11 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed: 
2017-05-11 04:12:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: HELO manager.aquatis.host 
2017-05-11 04:12:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2017-05-11 04:12:14 SMTP ERROR: HELO command failed: 
2017-05-11 04:12:14 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 
2017-05-11 04:12:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2017-05-11 04:12:17 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2017-05-11 04:12:17 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 
2017-05-11 04:12:17 Connection: closed 
2017-05-11 04:12:17 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

For some reason, this was working perfectly fine about a day ago. Now for some reason, it's not really working anymore. Here is my information below.

```html
<?php
require 'mailservice/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Timeout  =   3;
$mail->Host = 'webnode.aquatis.host';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '******@aquatis.host';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '***********';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('******@aquatis.host', 'AquatisManager');
$mail->addAddress($clientemail, $_SESSION["firstname"] . ' ' . $_SESSION["lastname"]);     // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo('no-reply@aquatis.host', 'No Reply');

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    //$messagetype = "failure";
     echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    $messagetype = "success";
}
 ?>
```

I have double checked the password and username and they are valid. I marked them as *'s so no personal information is shared. The SMTP server I'm trying to connect to is a cPanel server that's up to date. My Centos installation has the firewalld disabled as well.

Comment: Right, but you didn't follow the troubleshooting guide that tells you that the combination of `SMTPSecure='tls'` and `Port = 465` won't work. Use `Port = 587` with TLS.

Comment: I already tried that and it does not work sadly.